# Multiple match() against() in a MySQL query

Tags: mysql, index, performance, full-text-search, query-performance

Same question asked on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28509777/multiple-match-against-in-a-mysql-query), with no answers.

I'm using MySQL 5.7.17 on Windows 10.
I got this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl1`(
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `col1` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `col2` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `col1_idx` (`col1`) WITH PARSER `ngram`,
  FULLTEXT KEY `col2_idx` (`col2`) WITH PARSER `ngram`,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And I would like to make a query that `col1` *MUST* have `str1` and `col2` *MUST NOT* have `str2`, I run multiple `MATCH() AGAINST()` in a query,like this

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1
 WHERE MATCH(col1) AGAINST('+str1' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
   AND MATCH(col2) AGAINST('-str2' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

But this query returns nothing.

When I use `EXPLAIN`, like:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE 
 MATCH(col1) AGAINST('+str1' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
   AND MATCH(col2) AGAINST('-str2' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

it returns:

```
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+----------+-------------------------+---------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-----------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table     | partitions | type     | possible_keys           | key           | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra                             |
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+----------+-------------------------+---------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-----------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tbl1      | NULL       | fulltext |    col1_idx, col2_idx   | col1_idx      | 0       | const |    1 |    11.11 | Using where; Ft_hints: no_ranking |
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+----------+-------------------------+---------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-----------------------------------+
```

How do i make the query works? Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First, I think we need to assume that `str1` and `str2` occur in less than half the rows.

I think you will need to `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLEs`, one with list of `id` from one `MATCH`, one from the other.  Create an index on `id`. 
 Then `JOIN` the two tables.

It's messy, but FT wants to go first, yet you have two FT clauses in a single query.  Hence my attempt to turn it into two queries.

Since you are using 5.7, and it has the smarts to create an index on a derived table:

```
SELECT t3.*
    FROM ( SELECT id FROM tbl1 WHERE MATCH ... +str1 ... ) AS t1
    JOIN ( SELECT id FROM tbl1 WHERE MATCH ... -str2 ... ) AS t2  USING(id)
    JOIN tbl1 AS t3  ON  USING(id);
```

Give it a try. -- I am guessing.

Comment: Tried it, use `EXPLAIN` returns t1 and t2 use fulltext/fulltext type,  got 1/1 rows, and t3 use all type, got 28669993 rows, which is pretty big.

Comment: How big is each table?

Comment: The `tbl1` got almost 50million rows data.

Comment: Oh.  No `PRIMARY KEY` in `tbl1`?  Every InnoDB table needs some kind of PK.  What did you use instead of `id`?

Comment: I use `id` as `PRIMARY KEY` in tbl1. Forgot adding it in question.

Comment: Edited the question, sorry for that.